# How to verify a Stripe Connect, Account Deactivated web-hook?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe-connect

With all other web-hooks one can use an account's stripe access token to retrieve the event and then update based on the response of the API call, thus preventing possible spoofing. But with account deactivated, one is no longer able to use that account's stripe access token since the account is deactivated. Any other suggestions?  Basic auth is a no-go since each account can see the webhook url.

Comment: The fact that the api would return an error would be indicative that you're not authorized for the account anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe returns an error when you attempt to retrieve that event but that error is specific to this situation. You'll get an `authentication_error` if you attempt to retrieve it while if your weren't connected before you'd get `invalid_request_error`.

You can see an example in Ruby in this connect app [here](https://github.com/rfunduk/rails-stripe-connect-example/blob/eb3d11bcae6d35a9fa64ce529270478e2ce67939/app/controllers/hooks_controller.rb#L29)